# Слияние 2 коллекций в одну

Tags: java, коллекции

```
public class Main {

    String name;
    BigDecimal value;
    BigDecimal value2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Main> m = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Main> m2 = new ArrayList<>();
        Main main = new Main("1", BigDecimal.valueOf(2), BigDecimal.valueOf(0));
        Main main2 = new Main("1", BigDecimal.valueOf(0), BigDecimal.valueOf(3));
        m.add(main);
        m2.add(main2);
    }
```

Как можно объединить коллекции в одну чтобы получить результат // [name = "1" , value = 2 ,value2 = 3 ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, что данная задача сводится к тому, чтобы объединить потоки из обеих коллекций, затем сгруппировать элементы по имени и рассчитать суммарные значения для `value` и `value2`.  Для расчёта суммарного значения можно реализовать метод `merge`.  Tакже следует добавить конструктор и переопределить метод `toString`:

```java
public Main merge(Main main) {
    this.value = this.value.add(main.value);
    this.value2 = this.value2.add(main.value2);
    
    return this;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Main> m = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Main> m2 = new ArrayList<>();
    Main main = new Main("Aaa", BigDecimal.valueOf(2), BigDecimal.valueOf(0));
    Main main2 = new Main("aaa", BigDecimal.valueOf(0), BigDecimal.valueOf(3));
    m.add(main);
    m2.add(main2);
    
    Collection<Main> result = Stream.of(m, m2)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            mn -> mn.name.toLowerCase(),
            mn -> mn,
            (v1, v2) -> v1.merge(v2)
        ))
        .values();
        
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Вывод:

```
[Main: name = Aaa; value = 2; value2 = 3]
```

Comment: А можно сюда добавить проверку по имени? Просто имена могут быть с большой, или маленькой буквы как пример ( [name = "Волга"] ; [name ="волга" ])

Comment: Что значит _проверку по имени_?  Какой результат должен получиться в результате имен, написанных в разном регистре?  Можно просто в ключе группировать по имени, приведенному в какой-либо регистр (см. обновление), тогда в результате будет имя, соответствующее первому вхождению

Comment: Спасибо, у вас какая версия java? метода mege нету:)

Comment: Метод `merge` пишется вручную, в ответе показан его код, [онлайн демо](https://ideone.com/xrfbsq)